# How can I make an app by phonegap or cordova using ruby on rails?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova

I made a website by ruby on rails on c9 and I want to make this as a mobile application.

I found there are cordova, phonegap and etc.

I don't know how to use my previous code I wrote on c9 by using ruby on rails.

Is there any way to use my ruby on rails code to make an android application by cordova or phonegap.

Comment: There is a difference between a mobile app and web app. You can create an API and use that API with mobile app to communicate with the web app

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap uses primarily JavaScript/HTML5/CSS so it's not clear that you'd be able to "directly" reuse your existing codebase as a Phonegap application in the "now it's a web site, now it's a mobile app" sense. The answer that elimcjah posted does present some reasonable ideas though.

As a broader point, the first question when creating an app is what its value-add over a mobile site is (especially since you already have a functioning web site). I'd consider whether you want to make sure that your existing web site conforms to the principals of [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) or if you really do need to make this an app. It's actually not all *that* easy to convince people to install an app and keep it there, especially if there's not a perceived value add over their mobile site. There's also the additional expense and effort of submitting the app to the various play stores (which will likely require a subscription fee and may have a non-trivial "vetting" process; Apple's vetting process is notoriously stringent).